# Не работает GetComponentInChildren и создаются неправильно дубликаты объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Мне нужно чтобы в магазине создавались объекты сами при помощи скрипта с List, где уже указаны про них данные.

Но возникли проблемы:

1) У меня есть кнопка, у которой дочерний объект (по умолчанию Text у кнопок, я поменял на Image) - Image с компонентом Image.

Но вместо того, чтобы его изменять (`button.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().sprite = list.item_image;`), он изменяет компонент Image в самом объекте Button, а не в дочернем. Интересно, что если написать просто `GetComponent<...>...`, то свои действие не меняет и делает точно также, как и с InChildren.

2) Исходная модель, которая находится в файлах проекта, но не на сцене (шаблон) - objectButton меняется, хотя я сделал дубликат button и менял его, а не objectButton.

Т.е. как выше писал, он меняет Image в button и в шаблоне objectButton (где не должен менять),
хотя я писал `button.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().sprite = list.item_image;` - т.е. задал дубликату button, а не исходнику в файлах игры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
foreach (var list in List_of_things)
        {
            //Дубликат
            RectTransform button = new RectTransform();
            //Задаём дубликату исходную модель
            button = objectButton;
            //Изменяем дубликат
            button.GetComponentInChildren<Image>().sprite = list.item_image;
            //Создаём дубликат
            Instantiate(button, UI_content);

        }
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Во-первых, компоненты нельзя создавать через оператор new, только через `AddComponent`. Во-вторых, все компоненты - это ссылочные типы, строка `button = objectButton` не копирует, а записывает ссылку на старую кнопку в `button`, где вы уже и меняете спрайт.

Comment: Я уже это понял (использую `GameObject clone = Instantiate(objectButton, UI_content);`), но что насчёт GetComponentChildren? Почему вместо того, чтобы изменить дочерний объект (точнее его компонент), он меняет свой же компонент?

Comment: Если вы это поняли - исправьте вопрос. Насчет замены - перечитайте мое сообщение про ссылочные типы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мой ответ (сам нашёл решения):
1) Мне нужно всего лишь было получить дочерний объект и задать уже его Image

```
GameObject image = clone.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;         

image.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = list.item_image;
```

2) Спасибо RiotBr3aker, что дал понять, что я делаю ссылку. Исправил следующим образом

`GameObject clone = Instantiate(objectButton, UI_content);`

Всем спасибо, вопрос решён